# how to integrate google analytics for my universal app?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, universal

I have 2 universal applications, one for iOS, one for Android.

If the app were not universal, I will create 2 properties, with 2 different tracking codes.
But there, the app are universal.

So do I need to have 4 differents tracking code ?

For :
- iOS iPhone
- iOS iPad 
- Android 
- Android tablets

What do you suggest ?

Comment: Use the same tracking code for both Android and Android tablets. For iOS, I don't know. I do not develop on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Google Analytics plugin for [phonegap](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+google+analytics).